How can bounded orbits diverge arbitrarily far at late times?
While there are many definitions of chaotic dynamics, many commonly used ones require a positive Lyapunov exponent, which is defined as
$$\lambda := \lim_{t \to \infty} \lim_{\delta{\bf Z}_0 \to {\bf 0}} \frac{1}{t} \ln \left( \frac{|\delta {\bf Z}(t)|}{|\delta {\bf Z}_0|} \right).$$
Here there is a dynamical map with an implied initial condition ${\bf Z}_0$ in phase space, $\delta {\bf Z}_0$ represents an initial infinitesimal shift away from that initial condition, and $\delta {\bf Z}(t)$ represents the distance at time $t$ between the time-evolved state that began at initial condition ${\bf Z}_0$ and the time-evolved state that began at initial condition ${\bf Z}_0 + \delta {\bf Z}_0$.
But - while definitions again vary - chaotic dynamics are often defined to require bounded trajectories; see here and here. This requirement is meant to exclude trivial situations like systems that just exponentially accelerate away to infinity in a straight line. Even if we don't require boundedness in the definition, clearly many chaotic systems (like the double pendulum) have bounded dynamics.
But how are bounded trajectories compatible with a positive Lyapunov exponent? If all trajectories are bounded, then isn't $\delta {\bf Z}(t)$ also bounded over all times, and therefore the logarithm is as well - in which case the expression in the limit must fall off at least as fast as $1/t$ at late $t$?
I actually have a more basic confusion about the definition of Lyapunov exponents, which involves the very definition of $\delta {\bf Z}$. As far as I know, Hamiltonian phase space does not in general have a natural distance function (nor a vector-space structure, but I assume that the vector-like notation "$\delta {\bf Z}$" is just an abuse of notation). I won't include that question here, because I think it's basically a duplicate of The natural metric of a phase space and the Lyapunov exponent. I don't fully understand the answer to that question, but I figure that the answer to that question is probably important for answering this one.

Your question is similar to this, which however has a different focus.

The key to this is that $|\delta Z|$ is infinitesimal.  We're taking it as the limit approaches zero. In this sense, bounding does not cause any odd limitations like would occur with finite perturbations.  An infinitesimal shift in $|\delta Z_0|$ which results in a $\delta Z(t) = 1$ would result in an infinite $\frac{|\delta Z(t)|}{|\delta Z_0|}$, so boundedness does not automatically mean this exponent is nonpositive.

There are definitely some order-of-limits subtleties though. I agree that for any fixed time $t$, we can take $\delta {\bf Z}_0$ small enough to make $\delta {\bf Z}(t)$ as small as we'd like. But we're also taking the limit $t \to \infty$, which will make any initial separation $\delta {\bf Z}_0$ (no matter how small) eventually grow arbitrarily large.

Is the idea that we take $\delta {\bf Z}_0 \to 0$ even faster than we take $t \to \infty$, such that we push arbitrarily far back the time when the trajectories start to reconverge or hit the characteristic length scales of the phase space itself? It isn't obvious to me that this can be consistently done in a way that still gives a meaningful $t \to \infty$ limit.

Okay, I think I get it. The key is that we have to take the $\delta {\bf Z}_0 \to 0$ limit first - this definition does not work if we interchange the order of limits. The later the time $t$, the (exponentially) smaller you need to shrink down $\delta {\bf Z}_0 \to 0$ before you can be sure that you the two paths haven't started reconverging yet.

I guess this would also address the issue that the phase space might have geometric curvature; if you take $\delta {\bf Z}_0 \to 0$ small enough that $\delta {\bf Z}(t)$ stays arbitrary small, then you can probably ignore the effects of curvature on the geodesic distance $|\delta {\bf Z}(t)|$. Does that sound right to you?

@tparker Correct.  Assuming a manifold is smooth enough (I think C1 continuity is needed), for very small perturbations, the space is isomorphic to a flat space with no curvature.  (incidentally, I am still amazed at how effective that is, even after using calculus for years!)

As Cort's answer hints and you realize in your comments there, the order of the limits is important: you first take an arbitrarily close orbit and then let them evolve.
I think a numerical perspective sheds some light on the question: When calculating numerical Lyapunov exponents using methods that approximate the infinitesimals, we have to regularly normalize the distance (actually orthonormalize it, due to prototypical phase-space stretching) for the calculation to work.
As for $\delta {\bf Z}$, it lives in a flat space tangent to the phase space manifold — which doesn't mean you can ignore curvature, which in some systems is actually the origin of chaos — but does sidestep the question of a distance function for the phase space.

To clarify, by "$\delta {\bf Z}$", do you mean just the initial displacement $\delta {\bf Z}_0$, or the full trajectory $\delta {\bf Z}(t)$?

@tparker I mean the full trajectory. The calculation of LEs assumes a (local) linearized description is valid.

I now understand the answer. The key is the subtlety in the order of limits: somewhat unusually for physics formulas involving double limits, the order of limits is critical, and the formula no longer works if we interchange them.
I would actually frame my answer the exact opposite way as stafusa did (although we agree on the solution). I think it makes more sense to consider the two limits "from the outside in": you need to first consider a time difference $t$ of interest, and then take the limit $\delta {\bf Z}_0$ down to an infinitesimal size that depends on $t$. So the inner limit in some sense depends (exponentially) on $t$.
This dependence on $t$ is what makes the limit $\delta {\bf Z}_0 \to 0$ a little conceptually different from most infinitestimals that come up in physics. Usually, there are some local quantities - typically second derivatives that we can think of as representing some kind of curvature - that set the scale for how small we need to zoom in in order to consider a change as "infinitesimal" (i.e. we can think of the function as being locally linear). For example, for a 2D surface, the local radius of curvature (or Ricci scalar) sets the scale (far) below which we can ignore higher-order effects.
But by contrast, the limit $\delta {\bf Z}_0 \to 0$ in the definition of the Lyapunov exponent is in some sense nonlocal, because the size that you need to shrink $\delta {\bf Z}_0$ down to depends on the time difference $t$ that you plan to consider evolving out to. There is no time-independent length scale at which we can consider $\delta {\bf Z}_0$ to be "infinitesimal"; that length scale is not bounded below.
